# How to make a queued message broker in pure C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, publish-subscribe

## Background

I'm in a need for a queued message broker dispatching messages in a distributed (over consecutive frames) manner. In the example shown below it will process no more than 10 subscribers, and then wait for the next frame before processing further.

(For the sake of clarification for those not familiar with Unity3D, `Process()` method is run using Unity's built-in `StartCoroutine()` method and - in this case - will last for the lifetime of the game - waiting or processing from the queue.)

So i have such a relatively simple class:

```
public class MessageBus : IMessageBus
{
    private const int LIMIT = 10;
    private readonly WaitForSeconds Wait;

    private Queue<IMessage> Messages;
    private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>> Subscribers;

    public MessageBus()
    {
        Wait = new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        Messages = new Queue<IMessage>();
        Subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>>();
    }

    public void Submit(IMessage message)
    {
        Messages.Enqueue(message);
    }

    public IEnumerator Process()
    {
        var processed = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (Messages.Count == 0)
            {
                yield return Wait;
            }
            else
            {
                while(Messages.Count > 0)
                {
                    var message = Messages.Dequeue();

                    foreach (var subscriber in Subscribers[message.GetType()])
                    {
                        if (processed >= LIMIT)
                        {
                            processed = 0;
                            yield return null;
                        }

                        processed++;
                        subscriber?.Invoke(message);
                    }
                }

                processed = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<IMessage> handler) where T : IMessage
    {
        if (!Subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            Subscribers[typeof(T)] = new List<Action<IMessage>>();
        }

        Subscribers[typeof(T)].Add(handler);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe<T>(Action<IMessage> handler) where T : IMessage
    {
        if (!Subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        Subscribers[typeof(T)].Remove(handler);
    }
}
```

And it works and behaves just as expected, but there is one problem.

## The problem

I would like to use it (from the subscriber's point of view) like this:

```
public void Run()
{
    MessageBus.Subscribe<TestEvent>(OnTestEvent);
}

public void OnTestEvent(TestEvent message)
{
    message.SomeTestEventMethod();
}
```

But this obviously fails because `Action<IMessage>` cannot be converted to `Action<TestEvent>`.

The only way i can use it is like this:

```
public void Run()
{
    MessageBus.Subscribe<TestEvent>(OnTestEvent);
}

public void OnTestEvent(IMessage message)
{
    ((TestEvent)message).SomeTestEventMethod();
}
```

But this feels unelegant and very wasteful as every subscriber needs to do the casting on it's own.

## What i have tried

I was experimenting with "casting" actions like that:

```
public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage
{
    if (!Subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        Subscribers[typeof(T)] = new List<Action<IMessage>>();
    }

    Subscribers[typeof(T)].Add((IMessage a) => handler((T)a));
}
```

And this works for the *subscribe* part, but obviously not for the *unsubscribe*. I could cache somewhere newly created handler-wrapper-lambdas for use when unsubscribing, but i don't think this is the real solution, to be honest.

## The question

How can i make this to work as i would like to? Preferably with some C# "magic" if possible, but i'm aware it may require a completely different approach.

*Also* because this will be used in a game, and be run for it's lifetime i would like a garbage-free solution if possible.

Comment: So why not `public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage` ?

Comment: ...and have `List<Action<T>>` as your subscriber list?

Comment: But then, line `Subscribers[typeof(T)].Add(handler);` gives error ```CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Action<T>' expression to type `System.Action<Core.Messaging.Contract.IMessage>'```

Comment: And when changing to `Subscribers[typeof(T)] = new List<Action<T>>();` it also gives error ```CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Action<T>>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Action<Core.Messaging.Contract.IMessage>>'```

Comment: @spender this would require to change `private Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>> Subscribers;` declaration, but i don't know how, as the class itself is not generic in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you are trying to store lists of a different type as values in the subscriber dictionary.

One way to get around this might be to store a `List<Delegate>` and then to use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`.

Here's some test code that summarizes the main points:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>> Subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, List<Delegate>>();

void Main()
{
    Subscribe<Evt>(ev => Console.WriteLine($"hello {ev.Message}"));
    IMessage m = new Evt("spender");
    foreach (var subscriber in Subscribers[m.GetType()])
    {
        subscriber?.DynamicInvoke(m);
    }
}

public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage
{
    if (!Subscribers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        Subscribers[typeof(T)] = new List<Delegate>();
    }
    Subscribers[typeof(T)].Add(handler);
}

public interface IMessage{}

public class Evt : IMessage
{
    public Evt(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }
    public string Message { get; }
}
```

Comment: This indeed works - my only concern is about performance, isn't `DynamicInvoke` using reflections and all sort of unsuitable (for a game at least) things?

Comment: Ok, after some thought and small research i think that reflections should not be a problemem as long as there are few messages from time to time, and as far as i'm aware there should be no boxing in my case. So paired with pooling of message objects this should be totally garbage-free, which is - i think - a lot more important in my case. So thank you very much @spender.